# Cannot read property 'tapPromise' of undefined when build using css-minimizer-webpack-plugin

Tags: css, webpack-plugin

webpack.common.js

```
optimization: {
  minimize: true, 
  minimizer: [
    new CssMinimizerPlugin({
      test: /\.foo\.css$/i,
      //or already used
      test: /\.css(\?.*)?$/i
    }),
  ],
},
```

any suggestion what the problem is?

Answer (score 2):

This error is probably referring to

```
compilation.hooks.processAssets.tapPromise
```

You can use [processAssets hook](https://webpack.js.org/api/compilation-hooks/#processassets) with Webpack versions higher than 5.
`css-minimizer-webpack-plugin` migrated on processAssets hook since version `1.1.0`.

Basically, there are two options to resolve this issue:

- to lower version of `css-minimizer-webpack-plugin` to `1.0.0`

  ```
   npm uninstall css-minimizer-webpack-plugin

   npm install css-minimizer-webpack-plugin@1.0.0
  ```

or

- to upgrade webpack to higher than 5. If you're choosing this option, you probably want to research [migration docs](https://webpack.js.org/migrate/5/).